# Encountered an issue setting the value of a variable inside a Makefile function

Tags: function, makefile, wildcard, gnu

Directory structure (to run this example) looks like this:

```
example
 |-- Makefile
 |-- foo
 |    |-- foo.h (empty file)
 |-- bar
 |    |-- bar.h (empty file)
```

Makefile looks like this:

```
TARGETS=foo bar

define GEN_HEADER_RULE
$(1)_INCS = $(wildcard $(1)/*.h)
$(info $$($(1)_INCS) is [$($(1)_INCS)])
$(info $$(wildcard $$(1)/*) is: [$(wildcard $(1)/*)])
endef

$(foreach t,$(TARGETS),$(eval $(call GEN_HEADER_RULE,$t)))

all: 
    @echo "DONE"
```

Actual output is:

```
$(foo_INCS) is []
$(wildcard $(1)/*) is: [foo/foo.h]

$(bar_INCS) is []
$(wildcard $(1)/*) is: [bar/bar.h]

DONE
```

Expected output is:

```
$(foo_INCS) is [foo/foo.h]
$(bar_INCS) is [bar/bar.h]
```

I'm failing to understand why the value of the variable $(1)_INCS is not being set to be the output of the wildcard function? The wildcard function is clearly working without issue - as shown by the $info command dumping the output directly from it.

I have constructed this simple Makefile to demonstrate the same issue I have encountered in a much larger build system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to protect variables and functions from double expansion. Double all `$` except `$(1)` and you should see almost what you want (except for the second `$(info...)` that will produce more output than what you expect).

```
host> cat Makefile
TARGETS=foo bar

define GEN_HEADER_RULE
$(1)_INCS = $$(wildcard $(1)/*.h)
$$(info $$$$($(1)_INCS) is [$$($(1)_INCS)])
$$(info $$$$(wildcard $(1)/*) is: [$$(wildcard $(1)/*)])
endef

$(foreach t,$(TARGETS),$(eval $(call GEN_HEADER_RULE,$t)))

all: 
    @echo "DONE"

host> make
$(foo_INCS) is [foo/foo.h]
$(wildcard foo/*) is: [foo/foo.h]
$(bar_INCS) is [bar/bar.h]
$(wildcard bar/*) is: [bar/bar.h]
DONE
```

When using `foreach-eval-call` remember that there is a first expansion by `eval-call` and a second expansion by make when it parses the result as make syntax. You frequently need to escape the first expansion (`$$`) and even sometimes the second one (`$$$$`). See [the GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function) for a detailed explanation.